# How to parse this JSON where name has ','

Tags: oracle, pljson

I run next example

```
declare
    obj json := json('{"TR,A" : "OK" }');
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(JSON_EXT.GET_STRING (obj, 'TR,A'));
end;
```

and receive a message

```
ORA-20110: JSON Path parse error: expected . or [ found , at position 4
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.JSON_EXT", line 193
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.JSON_EXT", line 201
```

What is the work around?

Comment: have you tried JSON_EXT.GET_STRING (obj, '"TR,A"'))?

Comment: It does not work  , the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
declare
  my_json json := json('{"TR,A" : "OK" }');
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(my_json.get('TR,A').to_char);
end;
```

You should work directly with the `JSON` type. You should only have to resort to using packages like `JSON_EXT` if the type methods are insufficient for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but  `JSON` type gives me the same error when I try this
`declare
my_json json := json(
'{
  "T": {
    "R": {
      "TR,A": "OK"
    }
  }
}');
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(my_json.path('T.R.TR,A').to_char);
end;`

Comment: @Dimassik please try `my_json.path('T.R[''TR,A'']')`, see http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: And if you can control the value of the key name, try using a `-` instead of a `,`.